# swift nsdate give wrong output

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

A simple code, for converting string date to NSDate. But don't know why it return actual date - 1

```
var start_date: NSDate?
var end_date: NSDate?

let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

start_date = dateformatter.dateFromString("2016-09-01")!
end_date = dateformatter.dateFromString("2016-09-07")!

print(start_date)
print(end_date)
```

output

```
2016-08-31 18:30:00 +0000
2016-09-06 18:30:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set timezone in your `dateformat` to UTC

```
    let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateformatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")

    start_date = dateformatter.dateFromString("2016-09-01")!
    end_date = dateformatter.dateFromString("2016-09-07")!
```

This has resolve my issue.

Comment: I found your and Sweeper both's answer are useful and give me now correct output. So what is the default TimeZone swift assign for NSDateFormatter().

Comment: I think it's your local time zone @ManishJain

Comment: This will produce new problems. NSDate are stored in UTC, while the nsdateformatter take current timezone into account. with this code you will alter the dates to be 5:30 hours off.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar problems before. I think it's related to your time zone. And after some trying, I did this and it worked somehow...

```
let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: yourDate)
components.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
let correctDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components)!
```

Basically, switch the time zone to GMT...

I recommend you to create an extension:

```
extension NSDate {
    func switchToCorrectTimeZone() -> NSDate {
        let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: self)
        components.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components)!
    }
}
```